# Como redirigir todo el trafico que pasa por mi computador a una pagina web

Tags: windows

No se si se entiende el título pero lo quiero hacer es que si escribo en Google Chrome (o en cualquier otro navegador) *facebook.com* sea automáticamente redirigido a *www.google.com*

Algo así como lo que se hace con el host de Windows:
127.0.0.1 facebook.com // aquí estaría bloqueando el acceso a facebook

Y lo que quiero lograr es que cualquier pagina que solicite el usuario siempre lo redirija a www.google.com

No importa si puedo hacerlo con un programa, espero que me ayuden y gracias.

Comment: Dependerá si windows está en una LAN con servidores o es un PC  suelto, pero podrías utilizar las directivas de grupo (GPO), que prácticamente te permiten controlar "casi todo". Puede crear una directiva prohibiendo los dominios que quieras, o redirigiendo a otras URL´s. Echa un vistazo a las GPO  https://freyes.svetlian.com/GPOS/GPOS.htm  para familiarizarte y busca algo actual a tu SO.

Comment: Si un navegafor hace lo que pides, cualquier enlace que cliques en google. Te volveria a mandat a google.

Comment: Si quieres redirigir solo ciertas direcciones, puedes instalar un servidor DNS